# How to maintain page state after ajax request is completed and page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page where i am populating a Div on the basis of JSON response. Now what i want to know is that is there any means to save the state of the page to that current state unless until next ajax request/submit or any other event other then page reload occurs, in short i want to keep the result that i get from Ajax request even i refresh the page. At the moment this is my ajax code .

```
   $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: url,
                    data: {upload: UrlToSearch, ajaxRequest: 1},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        if (data == '') {
                            alert('No record Found');
                        } else {
                            fetchAndDisplaydata(data);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: are you using asp.net?

Comment: There's no way to save the page's JavaScript variables state besides using cookies.

Comment: State can be taken as some div populated when success case of `$.ajax` occurs

Comment: @OlegDubas sessions maybe? or .NET viewstate

Comment: You can store the json in a cookie or localStorage

Comment: @ElliotM: so you refer to me on using a Jquery Cookie?

Comment: @MarkRijsmus : sessions mean you save something on the server and then transfer it back to the browser on next page reload. What the OP wants is storing JS values W/O sending them to PHP

Comment: Webpages are stateless. ASP.NET worked around it using the viewstate, but that was definitely a bad idea and they came back on this with their MVC framework. You could probably re-implement the same kind of behaviour, or save what you need to save client-side (cookies, browser datastorage,...), but you should probably better look for another solution respecting the basics of web and not do the same "mistakes" Microsoft made (this is only my opinion though).

Comment: @OlegDubas i'm sorry my bad. :)

Comment: @temp-learn Jquery Cookies are good, but if you don't want to reference an external plugins, localStorage is just as good IMO. http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [pushstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) which has decent support. For better compatibility, see [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/History.js)

Here is a [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/246-ajax-history-state) on the topic.